# functions for tidyr's gather and unite using

Tags: r, apache-spark, tidyr, sparklyr

I have a data frame as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
m <- matrix(rep(1:28,each = 10), ncol = 28)
colnames(m) <- c("co1","col2", LETTERS)
df <- as_tibble(m)
df

newdf<-df %>%
unite("newcol", c(col1, col2), sep = " ", remove=F)  %>%
gather("col4", "col5", A:Z)
```

I am trying to write the following and have it work in sparklyr:

```
dataframe %>%
  unite(newcol, col1, col2, sep = " ", remove=F)  %>%
  gather("col4", "col5", A:Z)
```

Unite: Where newcol is the new column name that contains the united values of col1 and col2.

Gather: Where A:Z are the keys that are to be placed in the new col4. col5 is the new column that will contain the variable currently in columns A:Z

Does anyone have a user-defined function of a wrapper that will do the gather and unite function within the the spraklyr package perhaps using SQL?

Comment: I haven't tried in sparklyr, but with some dplyr backends you can just wrap the function in `do` and pass in the data as `.`

Comment: I'm guessing you've seen that this is issue #255 on the sparklyr GitHub. I'd also like to find an interim solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with SQL and the `DBI` library.

Assuming that you have your data.frame copied in Spark. (note that you have a typo in your `colnames` function call, you have set the name of the first column to "co1", not "col1").

```
copy_to(sc, df)
```

Now, you can create a new Spark table with your desired columns with this:

```
DBI::dbSendQuery(sc, "CREATE TABLE new_df AS 
SELECT CONCAT(t1.col1, t1.col2) AS newcol, t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col4, t2.col5 
FROM df t1 
            LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE (map('A', A, 'B', B, 'C', C, 'D', D, 'E', E, 'F', F, 'G', G, 
            'H', H, 'I', I, 'J', J, 'K', K, 'L', L, 'M', M, 'N', N, 'O', O, 'P', P, 'Q', Q, 
            'R', R, 'S', S, 'T', T, 'U', U, 'V', V, 'W', W, 'X', X, 'Y', Y, 'Z', Z)) t2 as col4, col5 ORDER BY col4 DESC")
```

Now, you can get the reference to this new Spark table and use it in Sparklyr:

```
ref_new_df <- tbl(sc, "new_df")
```

I hope this helps.

EDITED to show the result

```
> copy_to(sc, df)
> DBI::dbSendQuery(sc, "CREATE TABLE new_df AS 
+ SELECT CONCAT(t1.col1, t1.col2) AS newcol, t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col4, t2.col5 
+ FROM df t1 
+             LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE (map('A', A, 'B', B, 'C', C, 'D', D, 'E', E, 'F', F, 'G', G, 
+             'H', H, 'I', I, 'J', J, 'K', K, 'L', L, 'M', M, 'N', N, 'O', O, 'P', P, 'Q', Q, 
+             'R', R, 'S', S, 'T', T, 'U', U, 'V', V, 'W', W, 'X', X, 'Y', Y, 'Z', Z)) t2 as col4, col5 ORDER BY col4 DESC")
<DBISparkResult>
  SQL  CREATE TABLE new_df AS 
SELECT CONCAT(t1.col1, t1.col2) AS newcol, t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col4, t2.col5 
FROM df t1 
            LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE (map('A', A, 'B', B, 'C', C, 'D', D, 'E', E, 'F', F, 'G', G, 
            'H', H, 'I', I, 'J', J, 'K', K, 'L', L, 'M', M, 'N', N, 'O', O, 'P', P, 'Q', Q, 
            'R', R, 'S', S, 'T', T, 'U', U, 'V', V, 'W', W, 'X', X, 'Y', Y, 'Z', Z)) t2 as col4, col5 ORDER BY col4 DESC
  ROWS Fetched: 0 [complete]
       Changed: 0
```

Comment: Thanks for this. when I run this command I get the following Error: 
mismatched input 'LATERAL' expecting {<EOF>, 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'OR', 'AND', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'INTERSECT', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE'}(line 4, pos 20)

== SQL ==
CREATE TABLE new_df AS 
SELECT CONCAT(t1.col1, t1.col2) AS newcol  t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col4, t2.col5
FROM df WHERE t1 IS NOT NULL
                    LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(map('A', A, 'B', B,
--------------------^^^
                    '

Comment: @LeviBrackman It works for me. I have edited the answer showing the result I get. Please, could you check the syntax? Maybe it was a typo. Also, could you check that the column names are correct?

Comment: @JaimeCaffarel this is an amazing solution. I have a similar problem and I am getting the following warning `dbGetQuery(sc, query)
Warning message:
In max(n) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf` Do you know what that means? Thanks!!!!

Comment: @Noobie Thank you very much. I'm not sure about the warning message that you are getting. It sounds quite cryptic to me. In other `DBI` functions such as `dbFetch`, the parameter `n` is related to the number of rows to retrieve, with `Inf` for all rows, but I'm not sure why you're getting that warning.